# CruiseControl.Net (CC.Net) - Change made to existing .xml files to assist ccnet config doesn't load for email publishers

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

As part of my new role I've been given at work, I have a CC.Net build server that has multiple project configured in a way that the main ccnet config file references xml files for each individual project and each holds the steps/script to build that project.

I tried to add a couple of new email addresses following exactly the same syntax for the already present email addresses using new lines, but when I stop and start the cc.net service and build that project from the dashboard, the emails are still not sent to these email addresses. These new email addresses should gets email being set as buildmaster roles in either case of failure or successful builds. The old email addresses that were already there are still getting the emails.

Seems like a matter of the new changes not being loaded onto CC.net. SOS!

Here is a sample of the code block:

```
<email mailport="25" includeDetails="TRUE"  useSSL="FALSE">
<from>CruiseControl.NET-xxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com</from>
<mailhost>xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.com</mailhost>
<users>
 <user name="xxxx" group="buildmaster" address="xxx@xxx.com"/>
 <user name="xxxx" group="buildmaster" address="xxx@xxx.com"/>
 <user name="xxxx" group="buildmaster" address="xxx@xxx.com"/>
 <user name="xxxx" group="buildmaster" address="xxx@xxx.com"/>
</users>
<groups>
 <group name="developers">
     <notifications>
      <notificationType>Failed</notificationType>
      <notificationType>Fixed</notificationType>
     </notifications>
</group>
     <group name="buildmaster">
    <notifications>
    <notificationType>Always</notificationType>
    </notifications>
</group>
</groups>
```

Comment: can you post a sample of before/after of the email blocks? And have you tried re-booting your build server after changes take place?

Comment: Thank you @TheOptimusPrimus for the quick reply. I highly doubt it is the actual text I've added is the issue here as I can see the other project files having no difference in the email blocks against the project file in question. Its more so the fact that configuration changes aren't loaded. I am using a VM and I am not sure what would be the impact of restarting the server.

Comment: You can reboot VMs quickly. That or check the running processes on your build server and manually kill the CC.NET exes running.

Comment: Just restarted the server and then service once again. No change when I build that project, I don't see the email addresses that were added in addition to the two old ones.

Comment: Are you sure its the correct configuration file?

Comment: You were correct. There was a backup of the config files in another drive that I was shown while handing over the server and as per my understanding those were the ones picked up by the CC.net Server. It was not only till I went into ccservice.exe.config and checked the appSettings tag that I figured out actually where the referenced config files were. This has been solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check the location of your CC.NET config file. It's not always pointing where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

//in a way that the main ccnet config file references xml files for each individual project//

When you change a "sub file", it is not picked up by the filewatcher.

1. Change the subfile (as you have done).
2. Add a carriage return or a space or a comment (or ~something~) to the ccnet.config file.  (Essentially no changes, but you are resaving it).

This will trigger the filewatcher (on the ccnet.config file)......which will re-read the "subfile".